# How to move 3D Object With Touch Dragging Finger By the screen In android Unity Game

Tags: unity, c#, mobile, multitouch

My Code is As Followed:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Sphere : MonoBehaviour

{
    [SerializeField]
    private Touch touch;
    private float speedModifier;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        speedModifier = 0.01f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()

    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                transform.position = new Vector3(
                    transform.position.x + touch.deltaPosition.x * speedModifier,
                    transform.position.y,
                    transform.position.z + touch.deltaPosition.y * speedModifier);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I tried with this code but object is not even responding

Comment: Did you try increasing your speedModifier?
You can also put a :
Debug.Log(yourmovementvector); 
where you moving the object, to see if it even gets called.

Comment: According to the docs touch.deltaPosition is: The position delta since last change in pixel coordinates. Lets say you move your object 100pixels in one update (a lot already since you have like one frame time for that distance), multiplied by 0,01f results in object moved one pixel. Now if your screen is 2000px wide, most mobiles are a lot less, even if you drag from one side to the other, you would at most drag it 20pixels

Comment: I tried increasing speedModifier but it not working